# How is the intermediate compound 2-chloropropan-1,3-diol is formed when hypochlorous acid is added to allyl alcohol in the preparation of glycerol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, hydrocarbons

The expected product is 3-chloropropan-1,2-diol since secondary carbocation is more stable than primary but it is not formed.

I have surfed the internet a lot regarding this and none seems to be a simple, reasonable answer. Can anyone please  explain this mechanism clearly.

Comment: Read this https://doi.org/10.1039/JR9500001282

Comment: Yes thank you Waylander, ive read articles 260 and 261. It seems to be very complicated though. Is the reason really a tricky one or is there a simpler one? I'm only a high school student so I would appreciate a simpler answer? Nevertheless, thank you. -GW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be pretty simple, surprisingly.

I've asked my chemistry sir and this is what he said.
[image: see the underlined step]

In the underlined step, 2° carbocation is supposed to be formed.

But there is -I effect from OH group which makes the carbocation close to it, that is, 2° carbocation less stable.

Hence to avoid that, 1° carbocation is formed away from OH group and then the nucleophile 'OH minus' from HOCl attacks the 1° carbocation so formed.

Thus, 2-chloropropan-1,3-diol is formed as an intermediate instead of 3-chloropropan-1,2 diol.